# Overwrite `__getattr__` to access attribute of hidden class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, module):
        self.module = module
```

where `module` is an instance of another class `Boo` that has some attributes such as `length` and `height`. I want to overwrite `__getattr__` of `Foo` so that I can do

```
foo.height
```

where it internally returns the field of `foo.module`.
I tried overwriting `__getattr__` as so

```
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return getattr(self, name)
        except:
            try:
                return getattr(self.module, name)
            except:
                raise AttributeError
```

but it doesn't work. It seems to be stuck in a recursion, maybe because `getattr` uses `__getattr__` under the hood.
My question is, how do I do this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: simple `getattr(self.module, name)` will work.

Explanation: For attribute that in `Foo`, i.e., `module`, `Foo.module` will call `__getattribute__()` to find out `module`. For other attributes, i.e., `name`, `__getattribute__()` will raise `AttributeError` and call `__getattr__()`. Hence, overwrite `__getattr__()` to let it find attribute in `self.module` is enough and can avoid infinite call loop.

Full code:

```
class Boo:
    def __init__(self, height, name):
        self.height = height
        self.name = name


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, module):
        self.module = module

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.module, item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    boo = Boo(123, "boo_name")
    foo = Foo(boo)
    print(foo.module, foo.name)
```

STDOUT:

```
<__main__.Boo object at 0x102752fd0> boo_name
```

Answer (score 1):

The main point is that `__getattr__` is called only if an atribute is not found the usual way.

Knowing that you should delete the first three lines of your `__getattr__`. A: They would be called only if the `name` attr does not exist, i.e. uselessly and B: the mentioned infinite recursion starts (not found -> try `__getattr__`).

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self.module, name)
```

P.S. One question remains: why this way, isn't there a better approach?

Update: @hide1nbush was few seconds quicker and I agree with him that `return getattr(self.module, name)` is sufficient, i.e. get rid of the `try-except` too.

Comment: My code is just an example obviously. When I use the suggested changes in my case, my program weirdly crashes in the `__init__` of `Foo` without an error message.
Is it possible that by overwriting it in that way, other accesses to attributes of `Foo` are missed?

Comment: @jubueche Please show a minimalized version of code that you have a problem with.

Comment: Also, in my case, `Foo` inherits from two other classes, which might further complicate things.

Comment: Ok, yes I will try.

Comment: `except Exception` why are you catching all exceptions? what's the point of the `try-except`, you only really want to propagate an Attribute error

Comment: The problem is that it also inherits from `torch.nn.Module` and then other methods of torch don't work anymore. I think changing the overall code structure is a better approach in this case. Anyways, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the first method, you can use **super** python function. it works

I recommend you use the third method or first method, it much better.

```
from typing import Any
class Boo():
    def __init__(self, height, length) -> None:
        self.height = height
        self.length = length

class Foo(Boo):
    def __init__(self, module):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(module.height, module.length)
        self.module = module

end = Boo(20, 20)
fi = Foo(end)
fi.length
fi.height
```

the second method, you can use **setattr**

```
from typing import Any
class Boo():
    def __init__(self, height, length) -> None:
        self.height = height
        self.length = length

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, module):
        setattr(self, 'height', module.height)
        setattr(self, 'length', module.length)
        self.module = module

end = Boo(20, 20)
fi = Foo(end)
fi.length
fi.height
```

the third method, it will use class __dict__ built-in attribute.

```
from typing import Any
class Boo():
    def __init__(self, height, length) -> None:
        self.height = height
        self.length = length

class Foo():
    def __init__(self, module):
        self.module = module
        self.fsetattr()
    
    def fsetattr(self) -> None:
        for k, v in self.module.__dict__.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

end = Boo(20, 20)
fi = Foo(end)
fi.length
fi.height
```